# How to remove Weekends from a datelist?

Tags: python, function, loops, datetime

I am using the following code to remove weekends from a datelist:

```
def clear_weekends(date_list):
for i, e in enumerate(date_list):
    if e.isoweekday() == 7: 
        del date_list[i]
for i, e in enumerate(date_list):
    if e.isoweekday() == 6: 
        del date_list[i]
return date_list
```

For some reason though, it doesn't work and apparently random saturdays are not removed. Before, I had both saturday and sunday in the same for loop with the same if-statement. Then, it seemed not to delete any saturdays at all.

Does anybody know what is going on?

For a larger list, I can use

```
for e in clear_weekends(datelist):
if e.isoweekday() == 6: print("Saturday!")
elif e.isoweekday() == 7: print("Sunday!")
```

and I will still receive varying amount of saturdays (never sundays though).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As for your second example, if the `e.isoweekday() == 6:` is `True` then your `elif` for Sunday will never fire. So it's not surprising you never see that print out `Sunday!`. Change that `elif` to an `if` and rerun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to modify a list while you're iterating over it. You should delete them with a filter expression instead. Maybe a list comprehenseion?

```
def clear_weekends(date_list):
    return [d for d in date_list if d.isoweekday() < 6]
```